# Redirect output to standard out instead of file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, imagemagick

I am writing a java wrapper for `convert` (which is part of image magick). What I want to do is call a command like `convert -thumbnail 1024 test.JPG >(cat)` to make it print the thumbnails byte stream to standard out. Afterwards I want to read from this stream and store it in a blob store.
I'm having difficulties with the command above as it looks like it can't handle binary data. After printing the bytes it also prints something like `62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c62;c`.

I would like to avoid writing to a temporary file because I don't want to deal with any directory permissions.

What am I doing wrong in my command? Is it `cat` that can't handle the binary data or is it something else?

Comment: You may need to use a binary-to-text encoding scheme like Base64 for this to work.

Comment: @Haxiel you're right, the terminal couldn't handle the binary data but it turns out java can! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Output Filename section of the command-line processing](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#output) web page:

> Standard Out
>
> Unix permits the output of one command to be piped to another. ImageMagick permits piping one command to another with a filename of -.
>
> In this example we pipe the output of convert to the display program:
>
> `magick logo: gif:- | display gif:-`

Your command-line could then start with:

```
convert -thumbnail 1024 test.JPG -
```

... or optionally converted to other formats with the proper prefix:

```
convert -thumbnail 1024 test.JPG png:-
```

... at which point you could then pipe that output to your blob-store-reader:

```
convert -thumbnail 1024 test.JPG - | blob-store-reader
```

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is made for lines and text, but it doesn't care if it's handling binary data except for a few control characters. It's the terminal (your normal stdout) that can't cope with binary data and presumably gets stuck.

BTW, using "process substitution" for the required output file is like taking the scenic route. And, you should use it correctly, adding another `>` for the redirection. But, why at all? `man convert`:

> Specify 'file' as '-' for standard input or output.